# content overlapping while scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want id with div1 to be fixed and i have achieved that using position:fixed attribute

But content below div1 is overlapping with div1 while scrolling.

I want to avoid overlapping while scrolling.

Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="position : fixed; padding: 5px 0 0 5px; height: 140px; width: 150px;">dsfdsfdsfsdfds</div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    fhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>
    sfhskdfdsjfs
    <br/><br/>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aSfdD/1/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="div1" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff; height: 29px;  margin-top: -8px;  padding: 5px 0 0 5px;  position: fixed; width: 240px;">dsfdsfdsfsdfds</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
fhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you want to do something like this? 
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tJzeK)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" style="position : fixed; top:0; padding: 0px 0 0 0px; height: 50px; width: 100%; background: #FFF; opacity:1;">dsfdsfdsfsdfds</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
fhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
```

Comment: I am loading google maps in first div and in another div i have text data but using these style doesn't stop google maps from scrolling
ie div in which google maps is also scrolling i want to stop  scrolling of this div

Comment: i quickly tried to find solution for that, if you want to embed fixed location you can use iframe and fix it (the code you get when you enter location in google maps and there you have option to embed location to your website), i'll edit fiddle so you can see. there is other solution to embed google maps that you can find on google developers site, so which one did you use?
here is updated code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/psezm

Comment: here is another one, i found google map on fiddle and updated it with your code, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/4cSBA/
or you want completely disable scroll on map?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<div id="div1" style="position : fixed; top:0; padding: 0px 0 0 0px; height: 35px; width: 100%; background: #FFF; opacity:1;">dsfdsfdsfsdfds</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfssfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
fhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
sfhskdfdsjfs
<br/><br/>
```